# wptoolkit windows phone 8 AutocompleteBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I was able to connect the autocompletebox to a local database in isolated storage and it works. I'm stuck in trying to get the selected item using the selection change event. here is my class

```
[Table]
public class Hymns
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, DbType="INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull=false, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int hymnId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Audio { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Stanza { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried this code:

```
 private void acBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.AddedItems[0].ToString());
        }
    }
```

And I still don't get a value. I want to get the hymnId property.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. i used selection changed event handler to figure it out

```
private void acBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ItemViewModel firstItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ItemViewModel;
                if (firstItem != null)
                {
                    int fileId = firstItem.HymnId;
                    fileId = fileId - 1;
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + fileId, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `AddedItems[0]` to `Hymns`, for example :

```
MessageBox.Show(((Hymns)e.AddedItems[0]).hymnId);
```

...or broken down into lines for readability :

```
Hymne selectedHymne = (Hymns)e.AddedItems[0];
MessageBox.Show(selectedHymne.hymnId);
```